# Loop of subscribes inside a subscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm currently struggling with multiples/forEach subscribe inside a subscribe, I'm trying to retreive a list of objects then retreive their images thanks to their ID. Currently I've done this :

```
this.appTypeService.get().pipe(
  map((apps: AppTypeEntity[]) => {
    return apps.map((app) => new AppTypeEntity(app));
  })
).subscribe((apps: AppTypeEntity[]) => {
  apps.forEach((app: AppTypeEntity) => {
    if (app.Logo != null) {
      this.appTypeService.getPhoto(app.Id).subscribe((image: string) => {
        app.Image = image;
      });
    }
  });
  this.appTypeList = apps;
});
```

The thing is that, since it's not executing in order sometimes an object's image from the list will be empty. What I would like is to get all my images & then setting the `this.appTypeList`.

Here is my getPhoto just in case :

```
  public fileReader(blob: Blob): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.create((obs: Observer<string | ArrayBuffer>) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onerror = err => obs.error(err);
      reader.onabort = err => obs.error(err);
      reader.onload = () => obs.next(reader.result);
      reader.onloadend = () => obs.complete();

      return reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
  }

  public getPhoto(id: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.environment.get('webServiceUrl')}/photos/${id}/${this.endpoint.slice(0, -1)}/min`, { responseType: "blob" as "json" }).pipe(
      mergeMap((blob: Blob) => this.fileReader(blob))
    );
  }
```

I can't figure how to do that? I looked into `forkJoin` but I can't find out how to use it correctly in my case.

Comment: is `appTypeList` is array of strings? With each element of the array representing the returned value, `image`,  from `appTypeService.getPhoto(app.Id)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already understood the usage of [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), you are sort of on the right direction.

RxJS's `forkJoin()` will for the `Array.forEach()` loop to be completed before returning all the observables. If you are familiar with the usage of Promises in JavaScript, it is actually similar to `Promise.all`.

```
const observablesList = [];

apps.forEach(app => {
  observablesList.push(this.appTypeService.getPhoto(app.Id));
})

forkJoin(observablesList).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
  // handle the rest
});
```